# Не приходит смс аутентификации Firebase

Tags: firebase, логирование, sms

Клиент вводит свой номер в приложение. Приложение не показывает ошибок. Но смс клиентам не приходит. В результате клиент не может выполнить аутентификацию. Как просмотреть логи успешной доставки SMS в консоли Firebase?
Как просмотреть все недоставленные СМС и увидеть причину неудачной доставки в консоли Firebase? Заранее спасибо.